# Deleting document inside subcollection by using where in Firebase Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete document inside subcollection using where, how can I achieve this?

I can delete document inside subcollection using their document Id, but in some case if we don't know the id, we need to use where method.
This is direct method.

```
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('customerDB')
        .doc(customerId)
        .delete();
```

I have to achieve in this case:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('merchantDB')
.doc(merchantId)
.collection('store')
.doc(storeId).collection('customers')
.where('customerId',isEqualTo:customerId).
```

Answer (score 0):

Use get() to get snapshot from query, then you can delete the returned result.

```
// return a QuerySnapshot future, which contain list of matches documents
final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('merchantDB')
.doc(merchantId)
.collection('store')
.doc(storeId).collection('customers')
.where('customerId',isEqualTo:customerId).get()
// delete all matches
for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
  doc.reference.delete();
}
```